# How to add elements to a vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to add elements to a vector in my program. But I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. So far what I have below does not work. I get an error that says:

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall MySet::MySet(void)" (??0MySet@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main`

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class MySet{

public:
 vector<int> elements;
 MySet();
 void addElement(int value);
 int removeElement(int index);
 int sum();
 int size();
};

void MySet::addElement(int value){
  elements.push_back(value);

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int value;
  MySet set;
  cout << "Enter your numbers " << endl;
  cin >> value;
  while(value != -1){
  set.addElement(value);
 }

  system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: You never define your MySet ctor.Define it or remove your declaration of MySet().

Comment: doh!! ok got it. any idea why my numbers arnt getting added to my vector? when i run it , i enter 1 number then it enter and it just stops

Comment: move cin>> value into loop, your code just input once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first:**
You never define your MySet ctor.Define it or remove your declaration of MySet().

**second:**
`cin>>value` out of `while` loop,so just input once,you maybe want write code like this:
**EDIT:**

```
while(cin >> value){
  if(value==-1)
    break;
  set.addElement(value);
}
```

Comment: alright i got it working , but i dont uderstand the constructor part for MySet. im supposed to have a No-Arg Constructor that creates an empty set. how would i create an empty set? i put vector<int>(); in the MySet(), that is an empty set right?

Comment: @zerocool18 if you don't declare any constructor, the compiler provide default constructor for you and it will  init an empty vector for you.

Comment: i understand that , but for this problem im supposed to have a no args contructor that returns an empty set.

Comment: the c++ i use is very old lol , i ended up doin this   i put vector<int>(); in the MySet(),  and i dont get the error anymore. but is that returning an empty set?

Comment: You can do like this: MySet():elements(){//do your other work    }

Comment: `while(cin){  cin>> value;  if(value==-1)    break;` doesn't handle invalid non-numeric input / you should test that the parsing of `value` worked before using its value: `while (cin >> value) if (value == -1) break; else set.addElement(value);`.